# Unable to start steam: To run Steam, you must first connect to the Internet

Tags: steam

Only a messagebox comes up: "Steam.exe (main exception): To run Steam, you must first connect to the Internet"

- It worked earlier
- Other connections are working (http, vpn, skype)
- Firewall not blocking
- Router not blocking (don't need port forwarding afaik)

Did not found solution or any usable hint on the net so far.
Steam.exe version is 1.0.1065.11

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried repairing the install?  Download the latest installer, run it and select 'Repair'?

Comment: Two things: 1) Try deleting ClientRegistry.blob in the Steam folder 2) This last happened to me after installing PeerBlock, for some reason it thought Valve's servers hosted ads.  Be careful to check any & all software that could affect it, not just the firewall.

Comment: @MatthewRead Technically, they /do/ host ads - ads for the software available via Steam.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the Steam errors are quite vague, and can refer to a lot of different things, there's not an exact solution. However, the best way to troubleshoot it, is by eliminating various causes.

1. The most common issues can be solved deleting the **ClientRegistry.blob** file and force Steam to download a new and fresh copy of it.

   > The clientregistry.blob is a file for the program Steam. The file holds your registration data for your games. If you delete it the file will be restored and you will have all of your default settings on all games installed (like your name, spray, binds, etc)

   - Go to `C:\Program Files\Steam` (or the Steam directory that was specified during installation).
   - Locate **ClientRegistry.blob** and delete or rename the file to **ClientRegistryOld.blob**.
   - Next time you start Steam, the file will be forced to download.
2. Another common issue is the update list can become corrupt, this is solvable by deleting the **AppUpdateStats.blob** file and forcing Steam to download a new and fresh copy.

   - Go to `C:\Program Files\Steam` (or the Steam directory that was specified during installation).
   - Locate **AppUpdateStats.blob** and delete or rename the file to **AppUpdateStatsOld.blob**.
   - Next time you start Steam, the file will be forced to download.
3. If none of the above work, you should try to start Steam on another computer on the same network, to check for router problems.

   - If Steam doesn't start on another computer on the same network, it indicates that there is a problem with the **router**.

     - Your router might need **port forwarding**. [Portforward.com](http://portforward.com/) is a great site for tutorials on how to forward ports on a lot of routers.
   - If Steam starts on another computer on the same network. It's something with your computer that's causing issue.
4. If you have a **firewall**, try disabling it and start Steam.

   - If Steam starts your firewall might be blocking it. If you are using *Windows Firewall*, navigate to `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\` and press the "Advanced Settings" button on the left side. Then press the "Restore Default Policy" as [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DVuz.jpg) shows.
     If you are using another firewall, please consult the firewalls manual to figure out how to restore the default settings.
5. Some **programs** may interfere with Steam and it's connectivity.

   - Check your latest installed programs with [Steam's list](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289) for programs that might interfere.
6. Some **Spyware, Adware, and Viruses** also interfere with Steam.

   - Scan your computer for viruses, spyware and adware with an Anti-Virus program of your chose. If would recommend the [free version of AVG](http://free.avg.com/), if you are in need of a Anti-Virus program.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to most problems with Steam is to close Steam (shouldn't be a problem for you :P), then go into your Steam Folder (default C:\Program Files\Steam) and delete "clientregistry.blob".

This fixes most login problems, offline mode not working etc, because it causes Steam to re-update to the latest update (should be very quick as it mostly just verifies the files you've already updated).

Answer (score 1):

I found that PeerBlock 1.1 was causing this issue on my Win7 machine.  Disabling peer block fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Or just add the Steam exception to the lists (google it).

Answer (score 0):

I am using a Billion BiPac 7404VGOX and I had to change the firewall general policy here:

```
Configuration
-Firewall
  -General Settings
      -Policy (changed from Medium security level to Low security level)
```

I tried everything else(deleting files / reinstall / firewall off / av off/ NAT settings).