# Steam can't connect to the internet, first time installed

Tags: steam

I installed Steam on my laptop but it keeps saying that I need to connect to the internet. I've checked a bunch of sites but they all mention that you have to delete files, folders, etc. after updates. This problem happened after I first installed Steam so it doesn't have the steamapps folder or clientregistry.blob. I don't know if the solution is the same, since none of the required items aren't even there.

I have allowed my firewall to let Steam through, nothing. I've also turned off my firewall and nothing as well...

Comment: Check if your firewall is blocking it. This can happen fairly often, especially with first time installs

Comment: So far nothing has worked. I'm thinking virus now. Anyone know a good scanner I could use?

Answer (score 2):

The [required open ports](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8571-GLVN-8711) for Steam are:

> **Steam Client**
>
> - UDP 27000 to 27015 inclusive (Game client traffic)
> - UDP 27015 to 27030 inclusive (Typically Matchmaking and HLTV)
> - TCP 27014 to 27050 inclusive (Steam downloads)
> - UDP 27031 and 27036 (incoming, for In-Home Streaming)
> - TCP 27036 and 27037 (incoming, for In-Home Streaming)
> - UDP 4380
>
> **Steamworks P2P Networking and Steam Voice Chat**
>
> - UDP 3478 (Outbound)
> - UDP 4379 (Outbound)
> - UDP 4380 (Outbound)

You need to open those ports in your router to be port forwarded to your computer. Please see http://portforward.com/ if you have trouble doing this, as it explains it for many router models.

See also [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31115/unable-to-start-steam-to-run-steam-you-must-first-connect-to-the-internet?rq=1) question for more advice.